# PBS walltime: how much was actually used?

Tags: pbs

How do I figure out how much walltime (mem? vmem?) a PBS job (PBS Pro) actually ended up using, if it's not presented in the stodut/sterr logs?

Answer (score 0):

In Torque, this information is visible in the accounting log and in the qstat -f output for the job. In qstat -f, you wanted to look at the resources_used information.

This may have diverged somewhat in PBS Pro, but my guess is they have something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Wall time is always measured outside of the system.  That's why it refers to the "clock on the wall".

This is important because it often encompasses elements that some systems fail to measure, or measure poorly.  To illustrate, before a system can capture the time, some code must run to allocate the memory to capture the time, and then some code must run to assign that memory.  Everything before that happens is misreported to not have "cost" any time at all.

While I may have described the essence of wall time, do look to dbeer's excellent answer for capturing a time close to wall clock time (and hopefully solving your metric gathering problem).